# What is the probability that Erik will be selected as president of the committee?

Tags: probability

A committee is to consist of 6 members from among 12 people, including Erik. Three of the committee members will be given the titles: president, vice president and secretary. If the committee and the titles are chosen randomly what is the probability that Erik will be the president of the committee?

Comment: $6$ members including Erik, or $12$ people including Erik?

Comment: It should be the first

Comment: @barakmanos  The way I read this Erik is one of the $12$ people.  If the author meant Erik was already a member of the committee, he or she would have written "A committee is to consist of $6$ members, including Erik."  There would be no need to refer to the twelve people.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one president, and it's equally likely to be any of the 12 people, so 1/12.

Answer (score 0):

Since the committee is consisten from 6 memberand there are 12 people to choose from, the propability of Erik to be choosen in the committee is 1/2.
Since there are 3 title for  members, the propability of Erik getting a title is 1/2, given that Erik is choosen in the committee.
Since 1 out of 3 titles is the president, there is 1/3 propability of Erik getting to be the president, given that Erik is choosen to get a title.

Hence the propability of Erik getting the president title is 1/2*1/2*1/3=1/12.